# How can I use list comprehension to find a number of pairs that fit a given criteria - Python

Tags: python-2.7

For my intro Python class, I'm supposed to use list comprehension to find the number of pairs of values for x and y such that for a given value N:

a) 0 <= x < y <= N and

b) i^x + i^y is a real number (i is the complex number sqrt(-1))

I already did this using for loops in the following code...

```
a1 = 0
for x in range(0, N):
    for y in range(x+1, N+1):
        if 1j**x+1j**y == 0 or 1j**x+1j**y == -2 or 1j**x+1j**y == 2:
            a1 += 1
```

where a1 is my count variable to show how many pairs of x and y fit the criteria. For a value of N = 100, a1 is 1900

Now, I'm supposed to be able to achieve the same result using a one-liner list comprehension command. I've tried a few things, but I can't get it to work. What I want to do doesn't fit the syntax for list comprehension. Anyone know how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a genex for this, not a LC.

```
sum(1 for x in range(0, N) for y in range(x+1, N+1) if somepred(x, y))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm sure there are better methods out there, but the task is to use list comprehension, so I have to make it work with that method

Comment: So then put square brackets around the genex. Viola, instant LC.

Comment: OK so now I have the following line

    a2 = [sum(1 for x in range(0, N) for y in range(x+1, N+1) if 1j**x+1j**y == 0 if 1j**x+1j**y == -2 if 1j**x+1j**y == 2]

which yields an invalid syntax. I can see what the code is supposed to be doing, but I don't understand enough of Python syntax to understand why it's wrong

Comment: It's not showing correctly, but the 1jx and 1jy are in the code as 1j ** x etc - the correct form for 1j raised to an exponent x, etx

Comment: And please do forgive my ignorance. I'm sure for most everyone on here, this stuff is second nature. I'm having a very difficult time keeping up with the fast pace set in this course

Comment: Use `if` one time, and `and` or `or` to connect the relations. And the brackets go around the expression inside the parens: `sum([...])`. And backquotes around what you want to write as code.

Comment: Thank you very much. That runs fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to comment on [Ignacio's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39584700/3231557) but lack the reputation, sorry!  Just a tweak on your predicate: to shorten the expression a bit, you could say the following:

`1j**x + 1j**y in [0, -2, 2]`

which would have the same effect as:

`1j**x + 1j**y == 0 or 1j**x + 1j**y == -2 or 1j**x + 1j**y == 2`

Comment: OK thanks! That cleans it up quite a lot - I didn't know you could join the criteria in such a way.